# Does WordPress installation removes the current domain website?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website is some domain lets say 'x', and I want to install WordPress with Softaculous.
I want to know if I finish the installation, my current website on domain 'x', will still work until I publish my WordPress website or not?

Here is a screenshot, where I need to choose the domain name:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you mean you already have a website there before installing wordpress ?

Comment: Yes, in domain 'x' (but not in that directory)

Comment: generally installing wordpress will not overidde anything so i would tell you yes you can install, but you may do a backup of your site before ... it's always good to do backups to avoid bad suprise

Comment: and my current website will still be on active and accessible?

Comment: if it's not the same directory it will ... but make a backup before doing the installtion, i don't know Softaculous so am only sure at 90%

Comment: all right,  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

New WordPress can override your old WordPress if you:

- use the same directory for files (**so, use other, empty directory**)
- use the same database (**so, use new database**)
- use the same database prefix, default: wp_ (**if you have to use the same database be sure if you use other prefix, e.g. wp2_**)

I don't know what is your goal. Do you want to have two instances of WP at the same domain?

Comment: No, I have one website with without WordPress installed, If its in another directory it wont overwrite the current one